# Singleton Collection To Multiple Object Collection

Tags: java

So I was initially using a singleton list to pass data to Google Cloud API like this:

```
inputInput.setCsvInstance(Collections.<Object>singletonList("Ear"));
```

How can I change the `singletonList` to send multiple objects like this:

```
inputInput.setCsvInstance(Collections.<Object>singletonList("5.656346", "2.43485744", ...));
```

**EDIT:** I don't want to keep a singleton. I need to change it to multiple one, singleton doesn't allow me that. What keyword should I use instead of singleton is my question.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look up the meaning of "singleton".

Comment: So you want a _singleton_ list to contain multiple elements? A singleton list can only contain one element. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I don't want to keep a singleton. I need to change it to multiple one, singleton doesn't allow me that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A singleton list has only 1 element by definition. If you want a list with multiple elements, you can use `Arrays.asList()`:

```
inputInput.setCsvInstance(Arrays.asList("5.656346", "2.43485744", ...));
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I just had to use `Arrays.<Object>asList` for this Prediction API library.